# Newbie need Help python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a content like this:

```
aid: "1168577519",      cmt_id = 1168594403;
```

Now I want to get all number sequence：

```
1168577519
1168594403
```

by regex.

I have never meet regex problem, but this time I should use it to do some parse job.
Now I can just get sequence after "aid" and "cmt_id" respectively. I don't know how to merge them into one regex.

My current progress:

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=aid: ").*?(?=",)')
print pattern.findall(s)
```

and

```
pattern = re.compile('(?<=cmt_id = ).*?(?=;)')
print pattern.findall(s)
```

Comment: Please post your efforts.

Comment: Is this content part of a file or text containing many similar lines? Or is is that input all you are trying to deal with?

Comment: @MartinEvans Yes! It is just a example of my file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different approaches to designing a suitable regular expression which depend on the range of possible inputs you are likely to encounter.

The following would solve your exact question but could fail given different styled input. You need to provide more details, but this would be a start.

```
re_content = re.search("aid\: \"([0-9]*?)\",\W*cmt_id = ([0-9]*?);", input)

print re_content.groups()
```

This gives the following output:

```
('1168577519', '1168594403')
```

This example assumes that there might be other numbers in your input, and you are trying to extract just the `aid` and `cmt_id` values.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

**Example**

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'aid: "1168577519",      cmt_id = 1168594403;'
>>> re.findall(r'\d+', string)
['1168577519', '1168594403']
>>>
```

- `\d+` matches one or more digits.